# Filter logical columns

Tags: r

Not able to filter on logical columns below. Wanted to check if there is way to filter. If I filter based on false, NA row becomes all NA. I need rows with NA but with values in other column?

````
asd <- data.frame(Cat = c("A","B","B","A","B","A"), Start_num = c(2, 5, 1, 6, 6, 4), End_num = c(3, 7, 4, 7, 8, 5))

new <- asd %>% arrange(Cat,Start_num) %>%
    group_by(Cat) %>%
    mutate(Var=lead(Start_num)>End_num)

new <- as.data.frame(new)
new[new$Var != FALSE,]
      Cat Start_num End_num  Var
1       A         2       3 TRUE
2       A         4       5 TRUE
NA   <NA>        NA      NA   NA
4       B         1       4 TRUE
NA.1 <NA>        NA      NA   NA

```
````

Comment: Try: `asd[asd$c == FALSE,]`

Comment: great just edited my question. I just faces another challenge? can you help me?

Comment: Do you want `new <- new[Var | is.na(Var), ]`?

Comment: Try: `new[is.na(new$Var) | new$Var != FALSE,]`

Comment: or `new[is.na(new$Var) | new$Var,]`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to subset on the `TRUE` values but also have `NA` values, you need to subset both on `NA` and `TRUE`:

```
new[!is.na(new$Var) & new$Var == TRUE,]
# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Groups:   Cat [2]
  Cat   Start_num End_num Var  
  <chr>     <dbl>   <dbl> <lgl>
1 A             2       3 TRUE 
2 A             4       5 TRUE 
3 B             1       4 TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not using `%in%`?

```
new[new$Var %in% TRUE, ]
#   Cat Start_num End_num  Var
# 1   A         2       3 TRUE
# 2   A         4       5 TRUE
# 4   B         1       4 TRUE
```